# How to prevent opening the link in Dialogue Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, null, box

In a dialogue box, such as example 1B on [LINK](http://www.voy.com/230247/) , it begins with `SELECT`.  Then, I can choose various links to click.  But, when I return to `SELECT`, it also opens into a new page.   I just want it to stay there.  Remain stationary.   So, how do I prevent the link from opening.  I don't want `SELECT` to open anywhere.  Not in a new tab, new window, or even in the same tab.   I want it to Just remain null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna check for the selected value before opening the window like this-

```
<select id="siteTarget" name="target" class="searchTarget" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')}">
   <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>     
   <option value="http://bing.com/">(1)bing.com</option>
   <option value="https://google.com/">(2)Google</option>
   <option value="https://www.google.com/maps">(3)Google Maps</option>
   <option value="http://mapquest.com/">(4)Mapquest</option> 
</select>
```

Working fiddle url- http://jsfiddle.net/vpuyjc35/2/

Comment: oh.  This might be a tough one, but I only want the SELECT to remain stationary.   So, I want the 4 links to remain active.   So, those 4 links will remain live.   Only the opening SELECT should do nothing when scrolled upon..    So, I might be asking for alot !

Comment: @MediaReform now I completely understood your requirements, please see my updated answer and the working fiddle url. Let me know if I am correct and this is what you needed.